# requirement of root privileges for libpcap functions

Tags: c, libpcap

The `pcap_lookupdev()` fills in the errbuf variable when run as non-root user, while the same functions returns the value of the first available network interface when run as root.

Is this access disabled by the OS or the library. I think it is the OS. What is the right answer?

*This is not a homework question*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, when it comes to accessing files, devices and other services provided by the OS, access models in Unix (and, thus, Linux) are implemented *in* the OS.

Userspace programs are expected to just try whatever they want to do and gracefully handle any error condition by e.g. informing the user with a message.

This has several advantages:

- Maintainability: Access policy enforcement remains with the OS and can be configured uniformly. The administrator that wants to restrict access to a resource does so *once*, rather than having to configure this library here, than that library there, then...
- Configurability: The administrator can configure as simple or complex an access policy they need without being limited by each userspace implementation.
- Security: Userspace programs should not in general be trusted with enforcing access policy. It would be like having a wolf guard the sheep.

EDIT:

In your case, [`pcap`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap) needs low-level access to the network interface. Due to the security implications (capturing network traffic, generating arbitrary network packets etc), such access is limited to privileged users only. On Linux, for example, `pcap` needs the [`CAP_NET_RAW` capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) to be available to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the pcap functions require root privileges in order to work correctly. Might this be the problem?

Comment: Well, that is precisely my question. Why does it require _root_ privileges? Anyway, it has been answered, I must say, quite beautifully, by thkala

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on OS. Not all `pcap` functions require root privilege on all OS.

Ref to [Reference Manual Pages](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html), all special privilege requirements are listed respectively.