# How to lookup wireless device with pcap_lookupdev?

Tags: c++, linux, wireless, libpcap

Here's my code, so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int & argc, char* argv[]){


    char *net; /* dot notation of the network address */
    char *mask;/* dot notation of the network mask    */
    int ret;   /* return code */
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    bpf_u_int32 netp; /* ip          */
    bpf_u_int32 maskp;/* subnet mask */
    struct in_addr addr;

    char *dev; /* name of the device to use */

    printf("Asking pcap to find a valid device for use to sniff on.\n");
    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if(dev == NULL) {
        printf("pcap_lookupdev ERROR:  %s\n",errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Printing out device name.\n");
    printf("DEV: %s\n",dev);

    printf("Asking pcap for the network address and mask of the device.\n");
    ret = pcap_lookupnet(dev,&netp,&maskp,errbuf);
    if(ret == -1) {
        printf("Unable to retrieve the network address and mask of the device.  Error Description:  %s\n",errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Get the network address in a human readable form,\n");
    addr.s_addr = netp;
    net = inet_ntoa(addr);
    if(net == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to retrieve network address in human readable form.\n");
        perror("inet_ntoa");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("NET: %s\n",net);

    /* do the same as above for the device's mask */
    addr.s_addr = maskp;
    mask = inet_ntoa(addr);

    if(mask == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to retrieve device mask in human readable form.  ");
        perror("inet_ntoa");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("MASK: %s\n",mask);
    return 0;
}

/*
Output:

Asking pcap to find a valid device for use to sniff on.
Printing out device name.
DEV: eth0
Asking pcap for the network address and mask of the device.
Unable to retrieve the network address and mask of the device.  Error Description:  eth0: no IPv4 address assigned

*/
```

Here's my question:  What do I need to do to get pcap_lookupdev to look up wireless devices (i.e. wlan0)?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html) for **pcap_findalldevs** hints at the reason why **pcap_lookupdev()** is not finding any suitable network devices:

> Note that there may be network devices that cannot be opened with
>   pcap_open_live() by the process calling pcap_findalldevs(), because,
>   for example, that process might not have ***sufficient privileges*** to open
>   them for capturing; if so, those devices will not appear on the list

You probably don't have the necessary permission to capture traffic on any of the available network devices. Try running your program with *sudo*, assuming you have admin privileges on your machine.

See [requirement of root privileges for libpcap functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885841/requirement-of-root-privileges-for-libpcap-functions) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

`pcap_lookupdev()` will look up *one* device.  That might not be the device you want; if you have both a wired and a wireless interface device, it might well find the wired device, and that's *not* because it's not looking at wireless devices, it's because that happened to be the first device it found.

There's no way to tell it to look *only* at wireless devices.

To get a list of *all* devices that libpcap can handle, use `pcap_findalldevs()`.