# JNetPcap project

Tags: java, libpcap, jnetpcap

I have made a jNetPcap project for which the code is below:

When I try executing the program I got this as result in the console tag:

> "Can't read list of devices, error is"

and since jNetPcap depends on Libpcap C library which requires root privileges, it's obvious that's the reason why my program could not run. Could someone help me on that problem?

Note: I have tried to create .jar file in the src folder and create an .exe from this .jar file, but it throws the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jnetpcap/packet/PcapPacketHandler
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacketHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Pcap_capture. Program will exit.
```

---

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.jnetpcap.Pcap;
import org.jnetpcap.PcapIf;
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacket;
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacketHandler;
  
/** 
 * Here is the output generated by this example : 
 *  
 *  Network devices found: 
 *  #0: \Device\NPF_{BC81C4FC-242F-4F1C-9DAD-EA9523CC992D} [Intel(R) PRO/100 VE]  
 *  #1: \Device\NPF_{E048DA7F-D007-4EEF-909D-4238F6344971} [VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter] 
 *  #2: \Device\NPF_{5B62B373-3EC1-460D-8C71-54AA0BF761C7} [VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter] 
 *  #3: \Device\NPF_GenericDialupAdapter [Adapter for generic dialup and VPN capture] 
 *  
 *  Choosing 'Intel(R) PRO/100 VE) ' on your behalf: 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:42 EST 2009 caplen=1362 len=1362 jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=82   len=82   jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=145  len=145  jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=62   len=62   jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=164  len=164  jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=62   len=62   jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=54   len=54   jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=1073 len=1073 jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=1514 len=1514 jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=279  len=279  jNetPcap rocks! 
 */  
public class Pcap_capture {  
  
    /** 
     * Main startup method 
     *  
     * @param args 
     *          ignored 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
        List<PcapIf> alldevs = new ArrayList<PcapIf>(); // Will be filled with NICs  
        StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder(); // For any error msgs  
        
        boolean retval = false;
        /*************************************************************************** 
         * First get a list of devices on this system 
         **************************************************************************/    
        
        Process suprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suprocess.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream  is = new DataInputStream(suprocess.getInputStream());
       
        if (null != os && null != is)
        {
           // Getting the id of the current user to check if this is root
           os.writeBytes("id\n");
           os.flush();

           String currUid = is.readLine();
           boolean exitSu = false;
           if (null == currUid)
           {
              retval = false;
              exitSu = false;
           }
           else if (true == currUid.contains("uid=0"))
           {
              retval = true;
              exitSu = true;
           }
           else
           {
              retval = false;
              exitSu = true;
           }

           if (exitSu)
           {
              os.writeBytes("exit\n");
              os.flush();
           }
        }
            
        int r = Pcap.findAllDevs(alldevs, errbuf);  
        if (r == Pcap.NOT_OK || alldevs.isEmpty()) {  
            System.err.printf("Can't read list of devices, error is %s", errbuf  
                .toString());  
            return;  
        }  
  
        System.out.println("Network devices found:");  
  
        int i = 0;  
        for (PcapIf device : alldevs) {  
            String description =  
                (device.getDescription() != null) ? device.getDescription()  
                    : "No description available";  
            System.out.printf("#%d: %s [%s]\n", i++, device.getName(), description);  
        }  
  
        PcapIf device = alldevs.get(0); // We know we have atleast 1 device  
        System.out  
            .printf("\nChoosing '%s' on your behalf:\n",  
                (device.getDescription() != null) ? device.getDescription()  
                    : device.getName());  
  
        /*************************************************************************** 
         * Second we open up the selected device 
         **************************************************************************/  
        int snaplen = 64 * 1024;           // Capture all packets, no trucation  
        int flags = Pcap.MODE_PROMISCUOUS; // capture all packets  
        int timeout = 10 * 1000;           // 10 seconds in millis  
        Pcap pcap =  
            Pcap.openLive(device.getName(), snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf);  
  
        if (pcap == null) {  
            System.err.printf("Error while opening device for capture: "  
                + errbuf.toString());  
            return;  
        }  
  
        /*************************************************************************** 
         * Third we create a packet handler which will receive packets from the 
         * libpcap loop. 
         **************************************************************************/  
        PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {  
  
            public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {  
  
                System.out.printf("Received packet at %s caplen=%-4d len=%-4d %s\n",  
                    new Date(packet.getCaptureHeader().timestampInMillis()),   
                    packet.getCaptureHeader().caplen(),  // Length actually captured  
                    packet.getCaptureHeader().wirelen(), // Original length   
                    user                                 // User supplied object  
                    );  
            }  
        };  
  
        /*************************************************************************** 
         * Fourth we enter the loop and tell it to capture 10 packets. The loop 
         * method does a mapping of pcap.datalink() DLT value to JProtocol ID, which 
         * is needed by JScanner. The scanner scans the packet buffer and decodes 
         * the headers. The mapping is done automatically, although a variation on 
         * the loop method exists that allows the programmer to sepecify exactly 
         * which protocol ID to use as the data link type for this pcap interface. 
         **************************************************************************/  
        pcap.loop(10, jpacketHandler, "jNetPcap rocks!");  
  
        /*************************************************************************** 
         * Last thing to do is close the pcap handle 
         **************************************************************************/  
        pcap.close();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What do you want help with? If your system requires root privileges to run pcap, then that's what you do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [requirement of root privileges for libpcap functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885841/requirement-of-root-privileges-for-libpcap-functions)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you want help with (1) "Can't read list of devices" error or with (2) "Exception in Thread...." error.

Error message (2) means it cannot find the file specified(specified in the error message).

Extract the "com" and "org" folders from the jnetpcap.jar file and place them in the .jar file of your program. For example if the .jar file of your program is called "test.jar", place the above folders in test.jar
You can remove or put files/folders in a .jar file by using any compression program such as 7-zip.