# what is pcap, pcap_t, errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE]

Tags: c, pcap

Hi I am a newbie in C programming. Can anyone tell me what is errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE], pcap, pcap_t and how does pcap_lookupdev() work

```
    struct pcap_pkthdr header;
const unsigned char *packet;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

char *device;
pcap_t *pcap_handle;

int i;
device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
```

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745996/how-to-use-the-pcap-lookupdev-in-libpcap

Comment: Thx, but I do not understand what do they mean by device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE]

Some libpcap routines, if they fail, put an error message into a buffer, so that the program using libpcap can report the error to the user.  `pcap_lookupdev()` is one of those routines; if it returns `NULL`, that means it didn't find any device that it could open, so it puts an error message into `errbuf`.

> pcap

"pcap" is a name sometimes used for libpcap and WinPcap, or for the capture file format that it (and some other code, such as Wireshark) writes.

> pcap_t

A `pcap_t` is a handle used to read packets from a network interface, or from a pcap (or, in newer versions of libpcap, pcap-ng) file containing packets.  libpcap/WinPcap routines such as `pcap_open_live()` and `pcap_open_offline()` return a `pcap_t` from which you can read packets with routines such as `pcap_loop()`, `pcap_dispatch()`, `pcap_next()`, and `pcap_next_ex()`; in newer versions of libpcap (but not yet in WinPcap), you can also get a `pcap_t` by calling `pcap_create()`, set various options on that `pcap_t`, and then "activate" it, making it available to capture on, with `pcap_activate()`.

> what do they mean by device

Usually, a device is a network interface, such as `eth0` or `wlan0` on a Linux machine, `en0` or `en1` on a Mac, various other names on BSD, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, etc., or various somewhat cryptic strings on Windows with WinPcap.  On some platforms, libpcap may also let you capture traffic on your machine's USB interfaces (raw USB traffic - you could also capture on USB network interfaces, but those would just be like regular network interfaces).

Comment: And, no, "A pcap_t is a handle used to read packets from a network interface, or from a pcap (or, in newer versions of libpcap, pcap-ng) file containing packets." does *not* mean that a `pcap_t *` is a `FILE *` if it happens to refer to a file - it's not, and you cannot use a `FILE *` as a `pcap_t *`.